# Hide admin menu

Tags: wordpress

I am using the latest wordpress 3.2.1. I would like to let create a new admin to do ONLY this:
1) Manage order to change the order status to (e.g. approve..reject).
2) Able to view user only without the ability to Edit or Delete.
3) Accept email notification on new registered user and new order.

This would meant that when this new admin login, he is able to view only these 3 menu and All  other menu will be invisible. Could anyone advice?
I have tried many like the Adminimize, Admin Menu Editor, hide-admin-panels.. But all don works as it is a role based instead of user based.

Comment: In my opinion, this question should be migrated to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great Plugin called Members: Just create a new role, give it the capabilities it should have and I suppose WordPress will hide all the areas in the backend where the user does not have an capabilities to do any actions:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

This article also might be helpful - it is about using and extending the WordPress default role system:

http://www.blackbam.at/blackbams-blog/2011/07/02/digging-into-roles-and-capabilities-in-wordpress-extension-and-global-usage/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

For your needs, I believe that the plugin [Hide Admin Menu](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-hide-admin-menu-plugin/290744) can solve the problem. It allows us to hide admin menu items based on user role simply by checking checkboxes corresponding those roles.

The plugin works for admin role as well, and also works with admin bar menu.

Give it a try.